# ng generate component only creating .ts file

Tags: angular, command-line-interface

I'm new to angular and recently bought a theme called Metronic. I installed all the required stuff including the latest angular CLI version. When I run the command ng generate component test, it will create a test folder but only a test.ts file with no html and css.

In all the examples that I've seen, this command will always create html, css, ts... so I am confused why it would only create the ts file for me?

Any help appreciated, Thank you

Comment: hm.. weird.. could it be that the html is inlined in the component ts? which version of angular-cli did you install?

Comment: the version is 1.6.5, will copy paste the ts file below

Comment: import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  template: `
    <p>
      dashboard works!
    </p>
  `,
  styles: []
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}

Comment: can you try generating a component again with "ng generate component test2 --inline-style=false --inline-template=false" ? It should be the default, but in your scenario it looks like a config has changed.

Comment: that worked! thank you

Comment: you're welcome, i posted it as a possible answer to your question, if you like you can accept one of the answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a workaround:
Can you try generating a component again with "ng generate component test2 --inline-style=false --inline-template=false" ? It should be the default, but in your scenario it looks like a config has changed.

Settings according to [Wiki](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/generate-component)

As a long-term solution check out [David's answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48404897/ng-generate-component-only-creating-ts-file/48405059#48405059)

Answer (score 14):

In angular6 Inside the angular.json file you need to change "@schematics/angular:component {}"

make:
 "inlineStyle": false,
 "inlineTemplate": false,

should look like this:

```
"@schematics/angular:component": {
      "spec": false,
      "inlineStyle": false,
      "inlineTemplate": false,
      "prefix": "app",
      "styleext": "css"
    },
```

this will create your all three files (html,ts and css)

Answer (score 5):

**CLI command for creating '.ts' file in angular 6**

```
ng g c validation --flat=true --inline-style=true --inline-template=true --skipTests=true


'Flat' true        - for create file without folder
'inline-style'     - for create or skip the css file
'inline-template'  - for create or skip the html file
'skipTests'        - for create or skip the testing file file
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside the angular.json file you need to change

```
"schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "inlineTemplate": false
    }
  },
```

I face the same problem.This is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

More than likely, the Metronic theme modified their Angular/Cli config to only generate the component class. You can change this by going to the node_modules folder then go into @angular, then lib, then cli, and then finally config> schema.json. This file holds all the commands that run with ng generate. For example, if you search "component":, you will see the different things generated such as flat, spec, inline style, etc. (the default value determines whether or not it is done by default. I would start there in order to determine if they have modified it. If you are having trouble, an easy way to fix it would be to create a new angular project, and then copy the default schema.json settings and paste them into that file.

Comment: They seem to be already set to defaut:false in the schema.json file

Comment: I have all the correct values. inlineStyle and inlineTemplate are both false yet it still generates without either file. This happened all the sudden with an new angular 6 cli

Answer (score 0):

This works for me very well:

Make changes in angular.json from "true" to "false"

```
"schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "inlineTemplate": false,
          "inlineStyle": false,
          "style": "scss",
          "skipTests": false
        },
```

html, css, ts and spec.ts files added while generating Angular component.

Answer (score 0):

```
 ng g c <name> --flat=true --inline-style=true --inline-template=true --skip-tests
    --flat=true for no folder
    --inline-style=true for no css folder
    --inline-template=true for no html folder
    --skip-test for no test file
```

Comment: Same solution as https://stackoverflow.com/a/61577317/445976 posted two years ago.